# Is it possible to add inline comments in a multiline statement?

Tags: vimscript, comments

I have a function that looks like

```
fu! MultiLineTest(u, v)
    if    a:u != 2 &&
       \  a:v != 2

       return 'yes'
    else
       return 'no'
    end
endfu
```

Of course, the actual function is longer and more complicated.

Now, I'd like to add comments to the multi line expression, like so:

```
    if    a:u != 2 &&  " Neither u nor
       \  a:v != 2     " v must be 2
```

If the function is called now, I get an error:

> E15: Invalid expression: a:u != 2 &&  " neither u nor  a:v != 2     " v must be 2

I understand why this error is thrown. But I'd still find it nice if I could somehow add comments to such a multi line expression. Is this possible?

Comment: If you value your sanity, it's a good idea to give up on end line comments entirely.  `"` is used as both a string delimiter and a comment character, and thus its exact meaning depends on the context.  Now, this wouldn't be a problem in a normal language.  However, VimL is weird at best.  End line comments can create problems that are really hard to debug.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Not directly. But: if the comment applies to the whole line, you better place it above the line. If the comment(s) are each to indicate something about a portion of the line, you could consider splitting the line into exactly those pieces, and use variables named such as that they can *replace* your comments. It's better (IMHO) when the code "speaks" directly. E.g.

```
fu! MultiLineTest(u, v)
    let meaning_one = (a:u != 2) "there can also be details (if needed)
    let meaning_two = (a:v != 2) "other details
    return (meaning_one && meaning_two) ? 'yes' : 'no'
endfu
```