# How can I clearly document errorformat patterns in a plugin compiler file?

Tags: vimscript, comments

While testing out the [vim-go](https://github.com/fatih/vim-go) plugin I encountered [an issue](https://github.com/fatih/vim-go/issues/287) that I wanted to look into more closely. In a comment on the issue, the owner of the plugin writes:

> The text `read 0 byte, err read tcp 127.0.0.1:8800: i/o timeout: []`
>   is seen as an error line, so `makeprg` automatically parses it and
>   puts into the quickfix list.

I'm not familiar with Vim plugin development but with a bit of digging I found [the file where the parsing patterns are defined](https://github.com/fatih/vim-go/blob/73710fe6964c2f366682dba3550e2dcec7831949/compiler/go.vim):

> ```
> CompilerSet errorformat=
>       \%-G#\ %.%#,
>       \%-G%.%#panic:\ %m,
>       \%Ecan\'t\ load\ package:\ %m,
>       \%A%f:%l:%c:\ %m,
>       \%A%f:%l:\ %m,
>       \%C%*\\s%m,
>       \%-G%.%#
> ```

I read [the QuickFix error format documentation](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/quickfix.html#error-file-format) to understand these patterns, and I figured while doing so that I would add comments to the repository for the next reader to come along who isn't familiar with these patterns and tokens.

I got into the habit of using inline comments in this type of situation when [documenting complicated regex patterns in Python](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.X). It's really useful. I wanted to do the same here, so I tried using `"`:

```
" Define the patterns that will be recognized by QuickFix when parsing the output of GoRun.
" More information at http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/quickfix.html#errorformat
CompilerSet errorformat=
      \%-G#\ %.%#,                   " Ignore lines beginning with "#" ("# command-line-arguments" line sometimes appears?)
      \%-G%.%#panic:\ %m,            " Ignore lines containing "panic: message"
      \%Ecan\'t\ load\ package:\ %m, " Start of multiline error string is "can't load package: message"
      \%A%f:%l:%c:\ %m,              " Start of multiline unspecified string is "filename:linenumber:columnnumber: message"
      \%A%f:%l:\ %m,                 " Start of multiline unspecified string is "filename:linenumber: message"
      \%C%*\\s%m,                    " Continuation of multiline error message is indented
      \%-G%.%#                       " All lines not matching any of the above patterns are ignored
```

If this worked correctly, it wouldn't change the behavior of the plugin at all; but I found that QuickFix stopped working entirely after this change. If the syntax highlighting on GitHub is to be believed, most of these aren't actually being parsed as comments. I searched around and found ["Commenting is simple: put a double quote to the left of the text you want to comment" on the Vim Tips Wiki](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Backing_up_and_commenting_vimrc) but apparently it's not so simple as that.

[A question on SO points to a similar issue,](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24716804/inline-comments-in-vimrc-mappings) but I'm not defining mappings here and the different lines are actually part of the same command, so I can't just separate them.

According to an existing question here on Vi.SE, [it's not possible to use inline comments with multi-line statements.](https://vi.stackexchange.com/q/4211/800) So, how can I add a brief explanation for each pattern in the source, corresponding directly to the pattern where it appears in the code? I'd rather not throw it all into an overly-verbose multi-line comment in front of the `CompilerSet` command.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Settings like `errorformat` can be modified using the `+=` and `-=` operators. You can take advantage of this by setting an initial value and adding to it, with a comment accompanying each addition. You could do, for example:

```
" Define the patterns that will be recognized by QuickFix when parsing the output of GoRun.
" More information at http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/quickfix.html#errorformat
CompilerSet  errorformat=%-G#\ %.%#                   " Ignore lines beginning with "#" ("# command-line-arguments" line sometimes appears?)
CompilerSet errorformat+=%-G%.%#panic:\ %m            " Ignore lines containing "panic: message"
CompilerSet errorformat+=%Ecan\'t\ load\ package:\ %m " Start of multiline error string is "can't load package: message"
CompilerSet errorformat+=%A%f:%l:%c:\ %m              " Start of multiline unspecified string is "filename:linenumber:columnnumber: message"
CompilerSet errorformat+=%A%f:%l:\ %m                 " Start of multiline unspecified string is "filename:linenumber: message"
CompilerSet errorformat+=%C%*\\s%m                    " Continuation of multiline error message is indented
CompilerSet errorformat+=%-G%.%#                      " All lines not matching any of the above patterns are ignored
```

Maybe a bit verbose, but it should work (assuming `CompilerSet errorformat` behaves the way `set errorformat` does).

Comment: Thanks for elaborating. It [looks as though `CompilerSet` functions equivalently to `set` and `setlocal`](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/usr_41.html#41.13). I'll test it out and let you know if this doesn't work.

Comment: This seems to work, though it confuses the heck out of Vim's syntax highlighter. I've tried coming up with a less verbose solution - in Python I'd use `','.join()`, but setting options from variables/expressions seems like a huge pain in VimL and the docs are vague on how exactly `CompilerSet` is supposed to work, so I haven't figured it out yet

Comment: @Air actually, after using single quotes for the phrases within the comments instead of double quotes, my Vim highlights it perfectly.

Comment: @Air see: http://i.stack.imgur.com/dA6Gm.png